# Data-URI SVG background in CSS not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, base64

Ok, so here's what I'm trying to do. I have this code in my css file

```
.form_row .textfield:hover, .textfield_m:hover
{
    background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-color:White ;
    background-clip: border-box; -moz-background-clip: border; -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
    background-origin: border-box; -moz-background-origin: border; -webkit-background-origin: border-box;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%; -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%; -khtml-background-size: 100% 100%; background-size: 100% 100%;
    animation: pulse .75s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation:pulse .75s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate; /*Firefox*/
    -webkit-animation:pulse .75s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate; /*Safari and Chrome*/
    -o-animation:pulse .75s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate; /*Safari and Chrome*/
}
```

It's in a text input.

In every browser it seems to work fine, but it Firefox 5 it fails. All I get is blackness.

You can take a look at what I'm seeing here http://www.skylabsonline.com/holy/

Notice that in all the other major browsers it displays fine, but in firefox 5 it completely fails.

Any ideas?

ALSO, here is the SVG code for the Base64 above, and I used this site to convert it http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter , but base64 is always base64.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="myLinearGradient1"
                    x1="0%" y1="0%"
                    x2="0%" y2="100%"
                    gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="#feffff" stop-opacity="1"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#d2ebf9" stop-opacity="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1"
     fill="url(#myLinearGradient1)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Why do you use SVG instead of CSS gradient?

Comment: Portability/backward compatability

Comment: FWIW, this seems to look correct in Firefox 6.0

Comment: This is a bug in FF5. I have come across it as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Firefox had a bug that was fixed in FF6. [A hash(#) in the Data URI source](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=658949) will break the image.

A `#` in the content needs to be escaped as `%23`.

**References**

- [Firefox 6 Release Notes: Updating Add-Ons - URL handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/6/Updating_add-ons#URL.C2.A0handling)
- [data URIs: No support for query strings, etc.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs)

Comment: That did the trick for me it works as well for not encoded svg simply by using svg source as ```url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg  xmlns=[...]```

Comment: this bug is still present in FF41

Answer (score 1):

I just ended up having to toss the gradient in manually using CSS using something like -moz-gradient-linear()