# Firefox does not show data-URI SVGs

Tags: firefox, svg, data-uri

Firefox is giving me a hard time with data URI SVGs.
Here is a snippet from my Sass:

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 22 73"><path fill="#{$text-color}" d="M16.1 32.848l-2.38 2.066v-13.97l-5.67-4.918-2.38 2.066V4.132l2.38-2.066L5.67 0 0 4.916v27.932l5.67 4.92V22.23l2.38-2.066v19.67l-1.19 1.032v4.148l1.19-1.033v24.58l-2.38 2.065 2.38 2.066 5.67-4.918v-28.71l2.38-2.065V52.52l-2.38 2.067 2.38 2.066v.002l5.67-4.918v-13.97l-5.67-4.92"/></svg>');
```

Chrome and Safari are doing fine, but Firefox does not show it at all.
This is the error from Firefox:

```
Unclosed token:
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 22 73"><path fill="
------------------------------------------------------------^
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9835031/2162680) mention of a firefox bug in which `#` breaks the image. It should be fixed, but I tried to escape the hash anyway. Sadly that did not help.

Any other ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Ah okay, I tried to escape it with via backslash. `%23`did work! If you make this an answer, I can mark it as solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A # is the beginning of a fragment identifier in a data URI. It must be encoded as %23 if it's not to be interpreted that way.

It's a longstanding Chrome/Safari bug that they don't get fragment identifier parsing right.